# password verification non successive numbers with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I need to verify the password entered with this criteria with JavaScript (server-side c# would be great if possible) with showing messages:-

- password needs to be numeric.
- length <= 8.

and this is where the complexity stand :-

- I can't have like 11111111 or 22222222 or 55559852 or 12349421 or 98762534 from both sides

so I need to control the succession of the numbers for 4 digits wherever they are located. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i'm working on this js compenent [strenght password](http://rumkin.com/tools/password/passchk.php) `strenght password`

Comment: It's all very well validating it with Javascript, but the user can just amend the value after validation but before it's sent to the server..

Comment: @stuartd: No need to.. just overwrite the validating function with {return true}.

Comment: @Lain neat :)       .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try using this algoritm:**

**Javascript Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/b8xm4zkg/1/

```
function validatePassword(password)
{
    if(isNaN(password))
        return false;

    if(password == null || password.length < 7)
        return false;

    for(var x = 3; x <= password.length; x++)
    {
        if(password[x] == password[x-1] && password[x] == password[x-2] && password[x] == password[x-3])
            return false;

        var pNumber = parseInt(password[x]);

        if(pNumber + 1 == password[x-1] && pNumber + 2 == password[x-2] && pNumber + 3 == password[x-3])
            return false;

        if(pNumber - 1 == password[x-1] && pNumber - 2 == password[x-2] && pNumber - 3 == password[x-3])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**JS Usage:**

```
if(validatePassword("1233457638789"))
{
    //Valid
}
else
{
    //Invalid
}
```

**C# Code:**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mf4aLB

```
public static bool ValidatePassword(string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
        return false;

    if(password.Length <= 7)
        return false;

    string justNumbers = new String(password.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
    if(!justNumbers.Equals(password))
       return false;

    for(int x = 3; x < password.Length; x++)
    {
        if(password[x] == password[x-1] && password[x] == password[x-2] && password[x] == password[x-3])
            return false;

        int pNumber = int.Parse(password[x].ToString()); 

        if ((pNumber + 1).ToString() == password[x-1].ToString() && (pNumber + 2).ToString() == password[x-2].ToString() && (pNumber + 3).ToString() == password[x-3].ToString())
            return false;

        if ((pNumber - 1).ToString() == password[x-1].ToString() && (pNumber - 2).ToString() == password[x-2].ToString() && (pNumber - 3).ToString() == password[x-3].ToString())
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**C# Usage:**

```
if(ValidatePassword("1233457638789"))
{
    //Valid
}
else
{
    //Invalid
}
```

Comment: I do not intend to make fun of your time and effort, but aint a password validation in JavaScript kinda silly? Everyone could just open the console and type "var validatePassword = function(){return true}".

Comment: Sorry... I Added a C# Version! ;)

Comment: i apreciate the help @IgorQuirino how can i test the java script code can you mention the html equivalent please

Comment: @anass90 I added to my answer, ok?

Comment: @IgorQuirino i've done the test but in every value it shows Valid ! i didn't understood the logic !

Comment: Javascript or C#?

Comment: I added Javascript Fiddle and C# Fiddle, you can test online.

Comment: @IgorQuirino u're the best, solved ! 10'x!